# Adb can't connect to Android emulator running in docker and produces zombie processes

Tags: docker, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, vnc

I'm trying to set up android emulator to run inside docker container.

I've installed android sdk and emulator, but when I run emulatr, adb loses connection and starts producing zombie processes.

This is how I installed and created the emulator:

```
# sdkmanager "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64"
# echo 'no' | /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager \
              -v create avd -n x86_64 \
              -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64" \
              -g "google_apis"
```

This is the end of the `-verbose` output:

```
# /opt/android-sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds
x86_64
# /opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator -avd x86)_64 -noaudio -no-boot-anim -gpu off -verbose
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '192m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'SystemV/EST5'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x7f8c48f652a0] Adb connected, start proxing data
emulator: onGuestRecvData: [0x7f8c48f652a0] Adb closed by host
emulator: onGuestClose: [0x7f8c48f652a0] Adb closed by guest
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x7f8c48aa2020] Adb connected, start proxing data
emulator: onGuestClose: [0x7f8c48aa2020] Adb closed by guest
emulator: onGuestClose: [0x7f8c48a48090] Adb closed by guest
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x7f8c4840e020] Adb connected, start proxing data
...
```

When listing processes I see a bunch of `adb` zombies:

```
root      1090  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1092  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1094  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1096  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1098  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1100  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1102  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
root      1116  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z+   18:17   0:00 [adb] <defunct>
```

And they keep up spinning forever until I kill of the emulator.

I suspect that emulator doesn't boot up properly.

How do I debug this further?

Comment: Without knowing what does your emulator image Dockerfile include is diffcult to guess where is the problem. Are you sure you have all required dependencies to run the emulator?. I had a similar problem and I was able to fix it only after I installed  a display server (Xvfb for the record) and then run it inside container ( `export DISPLAY=:1 && Xvfb :1 +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER +extension XFIXES -screen 0 1024x768x24 &`)

Comment: I can share a `Dockerfile` but I've experienced the same issue in VirtualBox (running with `-no-accel` cause VBox doesn't support nested virtualization).